# wxGlade - Content from Frame don´t change the size

Tags: python, wxpython, wxglade

i have a general problem in my GUI (by wxGlade - Python 2.7).
Everything works - thanks to the people from stackoverflow for help) but when i change the size of the frame, the content doesn´t change the size. I can make it so little that you can´t see anything.

I would like to post some code -  but what do you need? Or is this a generel setting in wxGlade?

Thank you

Comment: Have you used sizers? http://wiki.wxpython.org/SizerTutorials

Comment: Try setting EXPAND property in layout for all the widgets. Post your generated python code here.